# expected value - two etaps

Tags: probability

We play the following game: Someone throws a coin to fall out of the first eagle. Let's say that the eagle fell in the i-th throw. Then the two envelopes puts at $ 2 ^ i $ and $ 2 ^ {i + 1} $ pounds. We get a random envelope and we have to decide whether we want to take this other or not.
Let's assume that we get envelope with $2^i$ pounds. What is expected value in second envelope ?

Look at my point of view:
$X$ - value in second envelope
$$EX = 2^2 * \frac12 + 2^3 * \frac{1}{2^2} *...*2^{i+1}\cdot\frac{1}{2^{i+1}} $$

Comment: Likely, `etaps` means `stages` and `eagle` means `tail`.

Comment: yes, you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given that one envelope has $2^i$. Therefore the other must have either $2^{i-1}$ or $2^{i+1}$. We also know that the sequence of tosses yielded:

$$\underbrace{HH\cdots H}_{i-2\text{ times}}X_{i-1}X_i$$
where toss results $X_{i-1}X_i$ must be one of:

\begin{eqnarray*}
TT && \qquad\text{(first $T$ occurs on $(i-1)^{th}$ toss: Envelope $2$ has $2^{i-1}$)} \\
TH && \qquad\text{(first $T$ occurs on $(i-1)^{th}$ toss: Envelope $2$ has $2^{i-1}$)} \\
HT && \qquad\text{(first $T$ occurs on $i^{th}$ toss: Envelope $2$ has $2^{i+1}$)}.
\end{eqnarray*}

These three results are equally likely (as conditional probabilities), so

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(X) &=& \dfrac{2}{3} 2^{i-1} + \dfrac{1}{3} 2^{i+1} \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{2}{3} 2^{i-1} + \dfrac{4}{3} 2^{i-1} \\
&& \\
&=& 2^{i}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Ok, so expected value in second evevelope is the same  as enevelope the we have got it. How is it possible ?

Comment: Because there are two alternatives: half of $2^i$ or double $2^i$. But you are twice as likely to get the half than get the double. So it balances out.